# Where is Laravel.log on GAE google cloud platform?

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I deployed my laravel application on GCP App Engine

https://MY-PROJECT-NAME.appspot.com/
"Whoops, looks like something went wrong." is displayed.
I want to check a error log. but I couldn't find laravel.log.
Where can I see the log file.

Comment: storage/logs/ is empty. It seems to have not installed fully.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [community documentation](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible), you can specify the log-file in your app.yaml file as follows:

```
env_variables:
  # Put production environment variables here.
  APP_LOG: errorlog
```

Regarding the error message, it seems that you may be able to solve it by updating your installer and project with:

```
composer global update
composer update
```

You can find more information about that [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/20874)

Answer (score -1):

The laravel log will be inside your storage directory

```
storage/logs/laravel.log
```